# In HTML "href" automate

Tags: html

if you remain to site is  "http: //www.demo.com/demo/index.php".
in this page, has two tags is 
`<a href="link.php?id=1">first</a>`
and `<a href="http://www.google.com">second</a>`, 
when you click "first", internet address is "http: //www.demo.com/demo/link.php?id=1", but
you click "second" why not is "http: //www.demo.com/demo/http://www.google.com " ?
I have no idea.but i alreadly try to it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Tom! The thing inside the `href` attribute is a URL. There are nice explanations on the web like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/understanding_url_tutorial.htm, http://de.slideshare.net/ProdigyView/url-parts-tutorial, or http://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url and there is also an official specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs have several components (e.g. the scheme, the hostname, the query string).

You can omit any number of them *from the left* and the URL will be resolved relative to another URL.

`link.php?id=1` omits the scheme, the hostname and the `/` that indicates the top of the path, so it is resolved relative to the current URL.

The second starts with the scheme, so none of the current URL is kept.

If you wanted a relative URI to there, then you would use a dot prefix as per the spec:

> A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")
> cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as
> it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be
> preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-
> path reference.

See [the URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) for further reading.

Comment: Small addition: You _can_ have a `:` in a relative URL, but then you must escape it: `:` → `%3A`. Then it is not recognized as scheme separator anymore.